# Call REST API with auth token with React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, api, react-native

This is a try of call a **REST API** that as an authentication token with **React.js**. I'm sending the token request as `POST` and it's been read as `GET`, can someone help me please?

```
componentDidMount() {
  fetch("theURL/api-token-auth/", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      email: "EMAIL",
      password: "PASSWORD"
    }
  })
    .then(res => {
      if (res.ok) {
        return res.json();
      } else {
        throw Error(res.statusText);
      }
    })
    .then(json => {
      this.setState({
        isLoaded: true,
        token: json
      });
    })
    .catch(error => console.error(error));
}
```

Comment: You are correctly giving method `POST`, so the error might be in the backend. However, the data you want to send should probably be in the body instead of in the headers. Try `body: JSON.stringify({ email: email, password: password })`

Comment: Doesn't make sense making a POST with no data sent in body

Comment: It's working now, but now how do I store token's value to do another fetch? @Tholle

Comment: Could you show us the backend ? Your fetch seems to be right.
Here is the way we are using fetch in my company, with a Auth code:

`fetch(route, {method: 'POST', headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json', auth: AUTHCODE}, body: JSON.stringify({data})})`
The authcode should only be used to confirm the user is coming for a good location. You should use the body for all the other data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are correctly using the method `POST`, so that's not an issue. However, the data you want to send should be in the `body` instead of in the `headers`.

```
componentDidMount() {
  const email = "test@example.com";
  const password = "foobar";

  fetch("theURL/api-token-auth/", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      email,
      password
    })
  })
    .then(res => {
      if (res.ok) {
        return res.json();
      } else {
        throw Error(res.statusText);
      }
    })
    .then(json => {
      this.setState({
        isLoaded: true,
        token: json
      });
    })
    .catch(error => console.error(error));
}
```